# how to create migration for already exist table in rails

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, migration

I have deleted the migration files in rails project. Now i want run the rails project in another system for that i need the migration files to create the table. please tell me how to create the migration files for already created tables in rails.

Comment: Why don't you use `rake db:schema:load`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You still have `db/schema.rb` file containing all tables and their details..you can use it by `rake db:schema:load`,this will load the schema into the database, which is faster than running all the migrations.

**NEVER DELETE YOUR MIGRATION AND MAINTAIN IT IN SUBVERSION/GIT**